# How to debug chain_spec.rs?

Tags: chainspec, debugging

I was trying to have a close look at how `chain_spec.rs` was constructed, and wanted to output to the console for debugging purposes, but was having some trouble executing `print` and `log::info`. So, I would like to know if there are any workarounds?

For example, in order to test the output of [from_string_with_seed](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_core/crypto/trait.Pair.html#method.from_string_with_seed), I tried displaying the type returned, but realized the type didn't have the appropriate implementations of the required traits in order for the `print()` or `info!()` to work without manually adding them.

***Adding info***

What I originally wanted to understand was how the default seed string `//Alice` generated the root key. The reason for my question was because my understanding is that seeds or mnemonic are generated from private keys, not vice versa. I do understand seeds can be used to recover keys, but that didn't seem like what `from_string_with_seed` was doing for a few reasons.

Therefore, I decided to play around with the parameter for the function to see what it would return in different scenarios, but ran into a wall actually printing it to the console.

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you want to debug? I mean when `Debug` ins't implemented, you need to derive the trait.

Comment: what kind of value do you hope to see with `print`?

Comment: Apol for the ambiguity, new to a lot of things, not just substrate - will ask better questions moving forward. Updated above with context.

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/5294/73 here I have explained how the private key is generated. Or better, how the uri is build.