# in the second tutorial i didn't had to specify a key for bob, how did it work?

Tags: substrate-node-template, tutorials

In the second [tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/simulate-network/) where we simulate a network with two nodes, we add Bob however we use `--bootnodes` option and we didn't specify the keys for bob.

what does that option do specifically, i assume it is used only for learning purposes (since it is copying the alice private key)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified the keys for `Bob` by passing the `--bob` cli flag. If you check the cli docs, you see the following above `--bob`:

```
/// Shortcut for `--name Bob --validator` with session keys for `Bob` added to keystore.
```

The private key for `Bob` is build by the following secret uri:

```
{DEV_PHRASE}//Bob
```

Where `DEV_PHRASE` is some known constant phrase, present in the Substrate code:

```
bottom drive obey lake curtain smoke basket hold race lonely fit walk
```

Comment: You can run your node with `--help`. It will print out the docs. In the code you will find them here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/2cd40882d27ef10437c691b2705e67fa97f7c074/client/cli/src/commands/run_cmd.rs#L209-L211